# OpenLayers supported image formats

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, image, format

I need to display ImageLayer in OpenLayers. Which image formats are supported in OpenLayers?

Comment: [Documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html) says "Instances of OpenLayers.Layer.Image are used to display data from a **web accessible image** as a map layer."

Comment: you right, the documentation says "web accessible image". im using IE , [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)  we can see that IE is supporting .TIFF format, but OpenLayers refuses to display it.

Comment: As tedious as it would be, it sounds like you'd have better luck making a number of images and seeing which one(s) work... the documentation work that they should have done :(